# MinGW and adding a Library

Tags: c++, file, mingw, sha1, getline

I want to use [this](http://www.tamale.net/sha1/) library with MinGW and i've been trying to get the example to work.

Is this possible? I've had a look at [using this](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampleDLL) but i've still not managed to do it.

Also, i'm welcome to alternative suggestions to sha1 hashing a string.

These are the errors I get when i try to compile sha1.cpp or the example program:

> sha1.h:29:17: error: extra qualification 'SHA1::' on member 'lrot' [-fpermissive]
>
> sha1.h:30:15: error: extra qualification 'SHA1::' on member 'storeBigEndianUint32' [-fpermissive]
>
> sha1.h:31:15: error: extra qualification 'SHA1::' on member 'hexPrinter' [-fpermissive]

Thanks.

**Part 2**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "sha1.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char* BYTES;
    ifstream myFile("word.txt");
    if (! myFile)
    {
        cout << "Error openning file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    while (! myFile.eof())
    {
        getline(myFile, BYTES);
        cout << BYTES << endl;
        SHA1* sha1 = new SHA1();
        sha1->addBytes(BYTES, strlen(BYTES));
        unsigned char* digest = sha1->getDigest();
        sha1->hexPrinter(digest, 20);
        delete sha1;
        free(digest);
    }
    myFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So at which point are you failing? Compiling the library? Linking it with you application?

Comment: You should post the error logs from mingw

Comment: These are the errors I get:
 sha1.h:29:17: error: extra qualification 'SHA1::' on member 'lrot' [-fpermissive] sha1.h:30:15: error: extra qualification 'SHA1::' on member 'storeBigEndianUint32' [-fpermissive] sha1.h:31:15: error: extra qualification 'SHA1::' on member 'hexPrinter' [-fpermissive]

Thanks.

Comment: You get these erros at what point? You'd better add further info into your question, use edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the extra "SHA1::" in the following lines in the file SHA1.h:

```
static Uint32 SHA1::lrot( Uint32 x, int bits );
static void SHA1::storeBigEndianUint32( unsigned char* byte, Uint32 num );
static void SHA1::hexPrinter( unsigned char* c, int l );
```

They should be modified into

```
static Uint32 lrot( Uint32 x, int bits );
static void storeBigEndianUint32( unsigned char* byte, Uint32 num );
static void hexPrinter( unsigned char* c, int l );
```

This because the functions are being defined in the class SHA1 and is unnecessary to define again that they are in SHA1. Note that the same unmodified file may be accepted by Visual Studio (I had the same problem few years ago)

Comment: thanks for your help but when i try to compile after I make the adjustments, I get the message "undefined reference to 'SHA1::SHA1()'" plus a few more messages relating to undefined references. Maybe i'm trying to bite off more than i can chew here!

Comment: @Novice Have you added sha1.cpp to your project?

Comment: I'm not using Visual Studio, i'm using MinGW

Comment: sha1.cpp should be in the makefile like other source files from your project

Comment: Sorry but i don't know what you mean by that as all i've been using is sha1.h and the example program shown on that website. How would you do it exactly? Thanks.

Comment: Probably you are compiling without makefile, calling g++ directly. In this case: g++ yourfile.cpp sha1.cpp -o program.exe

Comment: thanks so much! can't believe it was just the sha1.cpp bit i was missing, how stupid of me!

Comment: Hey, one more thing please. I've edited that original program to read abc from a file rather than using #define BYTES "abc". I keep getting the following message when compiling properly: error: no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ifstream&, const char*&) etc
Even if i comment out all the SHA1 stuff and just have it as read from file and print out "abc" using cout.
Does this mean I have to define this as a function in the sha1.cpp file or is there a way to do this without doing that? or am I wrong altogether? Thanks again.

Comment: @novice you should include <string> (the function is defined there) and remember that the function is in the namespace std, so std::getline(blabla, blabla) or using namespace std; getline(blabla, blabla). See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/

Answer (score 1):

I can vouch for [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) and [Botan](http://botan.randombit.net/). Both are great crypto libraries and I've used them both with Windows and mingw. They do sha1 and other hashes.

Comment: Thanks, will definitely look into those as I am interested in other hash functions as well.